# jQuery show next parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="step1" class="step">
                    <h1>Enter code</h1>
                    <p><input type="text" value="<%= @groupCode %>" name="group_code" class="span3" />
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">
                            Next &raquo;
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="step2" class="step" style="display: none">
                    <p>Hello World</p>
                </div>
```

Upon clicking the link (`.btn`) I am needing to show the next parent div (`#step2`). I am designing this as a registration process, so there will be multiple parent divs (all named with step{:id})

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use something like:

```
//This should access the parent (step1), then the next element (step2)
$(this).parent().next()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('.btn').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.step').next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $(".step a.btn").click(function(){
   var item= $(this);
   item.parent().parent().next().show();
  });
});
```

If you want to hide the current one and show the next one with some fading effect, you can do this

```
$(function(){   
  $(".step a.btn").click(function(){
   var item= $(this);
      item.parent().parent().fadeOut(400,function(){
        item.parent().parent().next(".step").fadeIn(300);
      });
  });
});
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/Jm7fW/15/